# gcc -M flag (phony runes) fast compilation

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, compilation

I have a relatively large project, it's compilation takes normally 13 mins.

I was trying to optimize it's compilation and I saw the -M flag in gcc man, it has something to do with phony rules in makefile.
I'm not an makefile expert, but adding this -M caused compilation to run in only 2 mins, can someone explain what this -M does and how I can take advantage of it to speed up the compilation?!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The -M flag is more about making sure you rebuild every file that needs rebuilding. But if it replaces a "always rebuild everything" then it certainly speeds things up. You should have a look at *ccache* to improve your build times further. Use both.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about phony rules -- it's used to auto-generate dependencies for C files.   See http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ for more information on how this all works.

This should not speed up build files by itself -- it's likely that on your second run (with `-M`), make didn't need to rebuild some dependencies that were built in the first run, making the second run faster.

Where this does become handy is that it generates an accurate list of which files your .C file depends on, which allows you to only rebuild the files you need to.

If you happen to have a blanket dependency that makes all .c files dependent on all .h files, and you replace this with the `-M` convention, then this would indeed make your average incremental build go faster (as you would avoid needlessly building various c files if you modify a .h file)